# C# Linq with datatables - select from one table what does not exist in the other

Tags: c#, linq

For example, I have two tables that look like this

DATATABLE 1

```
COLA  |  COLB  |  COLC 
 1       123      321
 2       321      333
 3       222      232
```

DATATABLE 2

```
COLA  |  COLB  |  COLC 
 1       123      321
 2       321      333
```

I want to select only row 3 from table one.

I want to be able to join the two tables together on the COLA ID, but then only select the rows from DATATABLE 1 that do noto exist in DATATABLE 2.

How can I do this in LINQ?

I would strongly prefer the results to be a datatable, or Ienumerable or something easy to change back into a datatable. if it's not possible i will manage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var rows = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
           join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() 
               on t1.Field<int>("COLA") equals t2.Field<int>("COLA") into tg
           from tcheck in tg.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where tcheck == null
           select t1
```

This ultimately performs a left outer join, and any rows from `table2` that are null means the record in `table1` doesn't have a match. I would recommend against using the `Any` method, as it could possibly enumerate `table2` for every row in `table1` (which for larger sets, this is bad). LINQ Join will enumerate both tables only once in order to find the matching pairs for the selector function you specify.

Comment: I just tried this out and get a "Specified cast is not valid." as my result. Not sure what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: One of your columns isn't specified as an int. See what `table1.Columns["COLA"].DataType` and `table2.Columns["COLA"].DataType` returns. I'm sure that one of them is set up as something other than an integer field (in which case you should change the `<int>` to the necessary data type and possibly cast).

Comment: I was sure they were both ints, but one was an Int64, and the other an Int32. I changed the one I can control to be Int64, and changed the two <int> to <Int64> and now I get the error `Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int64'. Please use a nullable type.`
I tried making the column a Int64? but datatable does not support it

Comment: I figured it out. I left the column Int64, but changed <int> to <Int64?> and it works great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be:

```
var dt2Cola = new HashSet<int>(table2.AsEnumerable()
                                     .Select(x => x.Field<int>("COLA"));

var dt1Rows = table1.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => !dt2Cola.Contains(x.Field<int>("COLA"));
```

Comment: I get a 
    
"Specified cast is not valid." Exception when I try this